# Should Thread.sleep be used when reading from a FIFO?

Tags: java, multithreading, file, file-read

Due to the fact that in almost every question regarding the use of Thread.sleep it is mostly indicated to use it only in certain situations, I come to ask you if it is correct to use it in my case or if there is a better way to do it.

The operating system is Linux(Debian), in which a bash script is running that is detecting when a device (more specifically, a storage device) is inserted/removed, and then writes into a FIFO a string under the type "ADD {path-to-dev}" or "REM {path-to-dev}".

I created a small app in java which makes use of two threads. The first thread will call upon a read method that parses the String to the standard output, after which it will wait(). The second thread will check if the FIFO is empty or not and then, when it sees that a String has been inserted then it will call notify() so the other thread will print the String in there and so on. Inside the loop where it checks if the FIFO has data or not, I call Thread.sleep(1000), and I am unsure whether this is a good approach or not. I will present the code which handles all the action.

First, the class which has the methods of reading:

```
public class Detect {

private File file;
private BufferedReader read;
private volatile boolean readable;
private static String readFromFile;

public Detect() throws FileNotFoundException {
    file = new File("/hardware_stuff/hardware_events");
    read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    readable = true;

}

synchronized String readFromFifo() {
    while (!readable) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted during the wait for read.");
        }
    }
    try {
        while (read.ready()) {
            readFromFile = read.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in reading from FIFO.");
    }
    readable = false;
    notify();
    return readFromFile;
}

synchronized void waitForFifo() {
    while (readable) {
        try {
            wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Detect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    try {
        while (!read.ready()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Sleeping due to lack of activity in FIFO  in thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Detect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    readable = true;
    notify();
}}
```

Next, the thread which will read from it.

```
public class ReadThread extends Thread {

Detect detect;
private boolean shouldBeRunning;

public ReadThread(Detect detect) {
    this.detect = detect;
    shouldBeRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (shouldBeRunning) {
        String added = detect.readFromFifo();
        System.out.println(added);
    }
}

public void stopRunning() {
    shouldBeRunning = false;
}}
```

Finally, the thread which will check if the FIFO is empty or not.

```
public class NotifyThread extends Thread {

Detect detect;
private boolean shouldBeRunning;

public NotifyThread(Detect detect) {
    this.detect = detect;
    shouldBeRunning = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (shouldBeRunning) {
        detect.waitForFifo();
    }
}

public void stopRunning() {
    shouldBeRunning = false;

}}
```

In main I just create the threads and start them.

```
    Detect detect = new Detect();
    NotifyThread nThread = new NotifyThread(detect);
    ReadThread rThread = new ReadThread(detect);
    nThread.start();
    System.out.println("Started the notifier thread in : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    rThread.start();
    System.out.println("Started the reading thread in : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Is there any alternative to calling sleep or another approach I can take to replace the sleep with something else? I have already read other questions related to this topic and I am still uncertain/have not understood whether this sort of case is indicated for sleep or not.

UPDATE: As @james large said, there was no need to poll for ready. I was not aware that if there is no line, the readLine() will 'sleep' and there was no need to poll it after all. I removed the notifier thread, and I simply kept the ReadThread which will call the Detect readFromFifo() method and it all works good. @dumptruckman, thanks for the suggestion. Although it doesn't apply to my case, I didn't know of the WatchService and it was a good read, good stuff to know. @Nyamiou The Galeanthrope, the timer would have been useful, but as I already said, I only keep one thread to execute the same method and it works as intended.@Krzysztof Cichocki, thanks for pointing out there are issues. I was aware of that, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: There are  so many issues here...

Comment: Can't you just poll using java.util.Timer?

Comment: Have you looked into using `WatchSerivce`? Sounds like it would be a lot easier. Here's some info on it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: What's the point of calling `read.ready()`?  Why don't you just _read_ it?  The `read.readLine()` call will "sleep" until there is a line available to read.  Periodically testing whether a device is readable is called _polling_.  The main purpose for which threads were invented in the first place was so that we would _not_ have to do polling:  Instead of having one thread that tests each device in turn, we simply have one thread for each device, and each of the threads waits for input.